# powerapps add picture modus how to add multiple

Tags: powerapps

I have an app where users need to upload pictures (preferably add the same time) and then it is added to a gallery.
But whenever I do media>add picture, it creates a box, and when I test the app and press the add image button that I created, I can only select one image.

Is it possible to upload multiple images at once using that add image thing?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to associate multiple images with a record in PowerApps. If you are using a Form control connected to SharePoint or Common Data Service, you can use the Attachment card to add multiple attachments.

But if you want to gather many images using the Add Picture control, you can use these steps:

1. Insert an Add Picture control. By default, it is added as a group of controls: the AddMediaButton control itself, and an Image box that shows what's currently added.
2. Select the AddMediaButton (not the group).
3. You can configure the OnChange property of the AddMediaButton to Collect the selected image to a collection.

   Collect(addedMedia,
       {
           timestamp: Now()
           image: AddMediaButton1.Media
       }
   )
4. Show the collection of added media in a gallery.

When you save the data, you will want to use a ForAll statement to save each image and associate it with the record you want. Those steps will differ slightly depending on what datasource you're using.

Can you share more about your setup?

Comment: what i now have is an connection to office365 email and whenver i make a photo using the built in photo control it shows it in a gallery.
when i press ssend email it emails the photos with a predefined name to a predefined email address.

when i insert your code it says under addedmedia the name is invalid?